# Fastest way to identify the combinations of items

Tags: javascript, python, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out a way to identify the combinations of items ordered together from a list of orders (order is given by Order ID) and their count. For example, in the following list, tablet and laptop are ordered together twice.

```
 ID    ITEM  
====   =====
 1     Phone
 1     Mp3 Player
 2     Mp3 Player
 2     headphone
 2     laptop
 2     tablet
 3     tablet
 3     laptop
```

following are the distinct combinations (only taking 2 at a time) and their counts:

```
Phone, Mp3 player - count:1
Mp3 player, headphone - count:1
Mp3 player, laptop - count:1
Mp3 player, tablet - count:1
headphone, laptop - count:1
headphone, tablet - count:1
tablet, laptop - count:2
```

How to program this in VB.net/python/javascript without continuous looping?

*(Advance apologies for I'm new to both coding and stack overflow)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what a "common combination" is?  Why are you missing some permutations such as `Phone, tablet` or `Phone, laptop` and I don't understand what you mean by "ordered in the same order".  You will need to describe better what you're trying to do before anyone can help.

Comment: Why not `Phone, laptop` and others?

Comment: Why do you need these combinations? Where is the orginal information coming from - user input, database etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're doing, though you specified it rather poorly.  You are performing both a *groupby* operation (based on ID) and then a *combination* operation of like elements with the same ID.

In python:

```
li = [(1,'Phone'),(1,'MP3 Player'),(2,'MP3 Player'),(2,'headphone'),(2,'laptop'),(2,'tablet'),(3,'tablet'),(3,'laptop')]

from itertools import groupby, combinations

[list(combinations(g,2)) for _,g in groupby(li,lambda x: x[0])]
Out[10]: 
[[((1, 'Phone'), (1, 'MP3 Player'))],
 [((2, 'MP3 Player'), (2, 'headphone')),
  ((2, 'MP3 Player'), (2, 'laptop')),
  ((2, 'MP3 Player'), (2, 'tablet')),
  ((2, 'headphone'), (2, 'laptop')),
  ((2, 'headphone'), (2, 'tablet')),
  ((2, 'laptop'), (2, 'tablet'))],
 [((3, 'tablet'), (3, 'laptop'))]]
```

If you want to print that in a more human-readable format that is like your output, do:

```
output = [list(combinations(g,2)) for _,g in groupby(li,lambda x: x[0])]
for id_ in output:
    for combo in id_:
        print([x[1] for x in combo])

['Phone', 'MP3 Player']
['MP3 Player', 'headphone']
['MP3 Player', 'laptop']
['MP3 Player', 'tablet']
['headphone', 'laptop']
['headphone', 'tablet']
['laptop', 'tablet']
['tablet', 'laptop']
```

Or, formatting exactly,

```
for id_ in output:
    for combo in id_:
        print('{}, {}'.format(*[x[1] for x in combo]))

Phone, MP3 Player
MP3 Player, headphone
MP3 Player, laptop
MP3 Player, tablet
headphone, laptop
headphone, tablet
laptop, tablet
tablet, laptop
```

Comment: Thanks rioppi. Any thoughts on making this distinct? Like (Laptop, Tablet = Tablet, Laptop)?

Comment: @Braggy: But `('laptop', 'tablet')` should be in the list - both have the ID `2`.

Comment: @Braggy you just now added some sort of "count" specification to your question.  I will not be addressing that.  I encourage you to play with the above code, and explore methods for merging two collections of things in different order.  (hint: `set`)